# CSS my elements are not floating properly

Tags: html, css, css-float

So, for some reason, in Dreamweaver it looks fine  [image: reference]

But on my site it is not floating them properly in any browser, I tried FireFox, Chrome, and IE8:

[image: my site]

Link to my site if you care: http://addisonbwilson.com/Portfolio/SUBPAGES/Photography.php

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Addison Wilson: Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CODE/pcss.css">
</head>

<body>

    <?php include ("../INCLUDES/navbarsubpages.php"); ?>

    <div id="imagewrapper">
        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0001-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0002-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0003-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->
    </div><!--wrapper-->

    <div id="imagewrapper">
        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0004-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0005-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0006-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

    </div><!--wrapper-->

    <div id="imagewrapper">
        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0007-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">
            <img src="../IMAGES/addyftw-picture-0008-preview-320w.jpg">
        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

        <div id="imagecontainer">

        </div> <!--imagecontainer-->

    </div><!--wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*The body is responsiable for the background image, the rest of the site is divided between the sub wrapper and the includes */
/*bground tile is from http://subtlepatterns.com/white-brushed/ created by Andre Schouten, crediting him here as per the usage agreement */
body {margin-top: 0px; background-image:url(../Portfolio/IMAGES/brushed_@2X.png);} 
/* navbar is a php include*/

#wrapper{width:980px; height:auto;}
#imagewrapper{width:auto; height:auto;}
#subwrapper{width: 980px; height: auto;}

#imagefull{width: auto; height: auto; background-color:#FFF; margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;}
#imagecontainer{width: 320px; height: 213px; background-color:#FFF; margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; float:left;} 
#textcontainer{width: 320px; height: 320px; background-color:#FFF; margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; float:right;} 

/* navbar and its many variations are for the navbar include*/
#navbarwrapper{positon: absolute; width:980px; height: 120px; z-index:30; background-color:#FFF;}
#navbar{width:980px; height:120px; background-repeat:repeat-x; z-index:31;}
#navbarlogo{width:210px; height:120px; float:left; z-index:32;}
#navbarcontent{width:770px; height:120px; padding-top:75px; float:left; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; background-repeat:repeat-x; z-index:32;}

/*Unordered lists which are used to handle drop down nav bar*/
#nav{
        list-style:none;
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        float: right;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
#nav li{float:left; margin-right:10px; width: 120px; position:relative;}
#nav a{display:block; padding:5px; color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
#nav a:hover{color:#fff; background:#000; text-decoration:none;}
/* drop down */
#nav ul{ 
    background:#fff; 
    background:rbga(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px ;}
#nav ul li{ padding-top:1px; float:none; list-style:none;}
#nav ul a{white-space:nowrap;}
#nav li:hover ul{left:0;}
#nav li:hover a{background:#ccc; text-decoration:underline;}
#nav li:hover ul a{text-decoration:none;}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{background:#000;}

/* general tag overides*/
h1{font-size:large}
h2{font-size:larger}
h3{font-size:medium}
img {border:none}
ul{ padding: 0; margin: 0;}
li{padding: 0;}



/*link modification*/
a:link{ text-decoration: none; color:#FFF; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
a:visited{text-decoration: none;color:#FFF; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
a:active{text-decoration: none;color:#FFF; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
a:hover{text-decoration: none; color:#FFF; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
```

Comment: So you want those to floated left to each other?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same ID in multiple elements. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `float: left;` to the `#imagecontainer` styles. It's not there in the online version.

Comment: I literally just re-uploaded it, why on earth did it not have that tag updated with it...

Comment: Ok, deleted the version on the web server and uploaded it again, it is working now XD I feel stupid...

Comment: just float left ? why not 31% width and make it responsive ?

Answer (score 1):

For each image `float:left;`

This floats each container that contain each image. Use this for what you have right now.

```
#imagecontainer
{
    float:left;
}
```

You can also do the same with inline styles. But CSS is cleaner.

Also, do not use multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes. Also, is there a reason you are using containers for each image? You could have one container with many images and use

```
.container img
{
    float:left;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that `img {float:left;}` will float **ALL** images on your page.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```
#imagecontainer{width: 320px; height: 213px; background-color:#FFF; margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; float:left;}
```

**to:**

```
.imagecontainer{width: 320px; height: 213px; background-color:#FFF; margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; float:left;}
```

and replace every `<div id="imagecontainer"` with `<div class="imagecontainer"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#imagecontainer{
   display:inline;
   margin: 0px

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#imagecontainer {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 1%;
  width: 31%;
}
```

and this

```
img {
  border: medium none;
  height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

check it, perfect as you wanted. Responsive too ;)